# Substitute every character after a certain position with a regex

Tags: regex

I'm trying to use a regex replace each character **after** a given position (say, 3) with a placeholder character, for an arbitrary-length string (the output length should be the same as that of the input). I think a lookahead (lookbehind?) can do it, but I can't get it to work.

What I have right now is:

- regex: /.(?=.{0,2}$)/
- input string: 'hello there'
- replace string: '_'
- current output: 'hello th___' (last 3 substituted)

The output I'm looking for would be 'hel________' (everything but the first 3 substituted).

I'm doing this in Typescript, to replace some old javascript that is using ugly split/concatenate logic.  However, I know how to make the regex calls, so the answer should be pretty language agnostic.

Answer (score 2):

If you know the string is longer than *given position n*, the start-part can be [optionally](https://www.regular-expressions.info/optional.html) [captured](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refcapture.html)

```
(^.{3})?.
```

and replaced with e.g. `$1_` (capture of *first group* and `_`). Won't work if string length is *<= n*.

[See this demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/yU0X2x/1)

---

Another option is to use a [lookehind](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) as far [as supported](https://caniuse.com/js-regexp-lookbehind) to check if preceded by *n* characters.

```
(?<=.{3}).
```

[See other demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/FSzbBg/1) (replace just with underscore) - String length does not matter here.

---

To mention in PHP/PCRE the start-part could simply be [skipped](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24535912/5527985) like this: [`^.{1,3}(*SKIP)(*F)|.`](https://regex101.com/r/JAuIF3/1)

Comment: The length is completely arbitrary -- could be empty, 2 characters, or 50.  The second regex (with lookbehind, I had a feeling that was going to be involved) solved it, thanks!